# Slow IDENTITY asp.net functions

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using Identity for my webapi application to manage my users.
All of the code that is related to the UserManager class are functioning really slow. 20 second + .
Ive tried both Async and regular functions/tasks

For example:

```
Task<ApplicationUser> user = this.AppUserManager.FindAsync(login.userName, login.password);
```

is for authenticating username and password.

and also:

```
this.AppUserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id, "Client")
```

is the same.

I Believe this has something to do with the EF functioning slow, but THIS slow?

my connectionstring is:

```
 <add name="ConnStr" connectionString="Server=tcp:*****.database.windows.net,1433;Data Source=******.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=*****;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=*******;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Well, first off.. you should be using await with async functions.

Comment: as i said @ErikFunkenbusch i already did try it wit ASYNC

Comment: The example you gave uses an async function without the await keyword.